# Replace.string with a URL as parameter

Tags: url, str-replace

Below I have this code:

```
string _strTemplate = _strDownloadTemplate + IDReq + "/" + _strFileName;
Uri url = new Uri(_strTemplate);
```

As you can see, I'm converting the strTemplate (which carries the link of a page that I need to sent by email for the user) to a URL Format. My email body has several fields that I'm replacing with the correct value:

```
strMailMessage = strMailMessage.Replace("_LinkTemplate", url);
```

I'm getting an error because the method string.Replace takes strings as parameters only.
Is there a way to get around this?
I was thinking about pass the URL value through my page (page.aspx) but if there's a way to do so through this method, it would be better for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is C# and .NET, yes, `String.Replace()` works with strings.

Did you try:

```
strMailMessage = strMailMessage.Replace("_LinkTemplate", url.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for the reply, yes it is C#.
When I do this (url.ToString()) it works, but then when I receive the email, the field ("_LinkTemplate") shows the URL as a string, and I need it to be showed as a URL, treated as a hyperlink, so the user can click it. I hope I was clear. I can attach printscreens if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: You have not provided a sufficient description for this issue. First of all, a URL *is* a string. Did you mean that you need a `Uri`? If so, please show why you need a `Uri`.

Comment: My bad, sorry Jonathan. Already found my mistake, it's something else, nothing to do with string.Replace, this is working fine
Sorry again for the waste of time :(